# How I can invoke lambda with a delay?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sleep

How I can invoke lambda with a delay in python?
  After execute some line of code in lambda function, I need to sleep the 
  function for 5 sec and then continue.

How can i do this in python.
  I tried the simple way sleep(5), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't just use usual function instead of lambda? You should use lambdas only for some simple actions.

Comment: I agree with Lev Zekharov. Is there any specific reasons for you to use lambda functions instead of using a normal function?

Comment: Add details on what you have which didn't work.

Comment: @Parvathy please show some code. Lev, He's talking about AWS Lambda (serverless), and those are not just for simple actions

Comment: Duplicate of [invoke lambda function with hours delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46897859/invoke-lambda-function-with-hours-delay).

Answer (score 5):

Using `sleep()` in a lambda function will make you pay for nothing. Think about refactoring your code to execute as fast as possible and not adding additional sleeps in lambda functions (or in code at all ;)).

That said, a simple

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
```

should actually make your code sleep for 5 seconds in python - no matter if executed in a lambda or not. Ensure the timeout of your lambda matches the sum of your execution time and sleep time to not get unexpected timeouts.

Comment: Be careful by using sleep in python lambda, it can create a weird loop and trigger the lambda multiple times. Keen to hear if anyone had the same experience.

Comment: Has anyone encountered time.sleep(x) simply not working within a Lambda function?  I have a case where I needed to sleep to allow enough time for something to propagate to another region.  I tried sleeping for 5, then 10, then 20, etc. but I noticed that the sleep never occurred - total elapsed time in my function was always less than 6 seconds.

Comment: I have had some weird sleep related lambda behavior, where it sometimes triggers a new run of the lambda.

Comment: the sleep triggers the same lambda function multiple times.

Comment: ^ Check your function timeouts. If the sleep is pushing beyond the timeout, the invocation 'fails' and (if it's an async invocation) re-triggers.

Answer (score 2):

Double check that your lambda function basic settings does not have a timeout less than 5 seconds.  I think it defaults to 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sleep()` method to create delay in the code execution.
First you need to import `import time` to your function and add the time method in your code.

```
import time

time.sleep(5) # this will make the execution sleep for 5 seconds
```

Please note that the Default time out of AWS Lambda function is `3 seconds` so, increase the timeout time which is more than `5 seconds` say `8 seconds`
else your code execution will timeout.