# Fire aws lambda at a specific time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, scheduler, job-scheduling

Let's say I have a booking system where I want to fire an aws lambda function to send an email or message to users, 10 minutes before their booking starts. I have looked online and found few solutions.

**AWS Lambda + CloudWatch + DynamoDB:**

Someone suggested adding the job to dynamodb and setting the TTL to when I want to notify the user and then connect cloudwatch to listen to remove triggers on the dynamodb. I did not like this method as it seems like a hacky way to do it.

**ATrigger**

This website provides a rest api which you can use to set up a scheduling job in the future. This is exactly what I need but the last update on their social media was in 2018. So probably not maintained.

Comment: Can the booking system send an SNS message 10 minutes before? If yes, then this SNS msg can trigger the lambda.

Comment: @Marcin That is exactly what I needed :) . It can send a message for up to two weeks but I can get around that but extending it every two weeks. Thank you so much. Please add it as a answer so I can accept it

Comment: Answer  added. Glad its helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the accepted solution is to have a booking system to send an SNS message 10 minutes before the booking start. The SNS would then trigger lambda.

Answer (score 1):

I believe using SNS is fine in your case. However, I want to show you an alternative. Depending on how you schedule your trigger, you could also start a **Step Function execution** which will trigger your Lambda function at a certain point. Step Function executions can run for [up to a year](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits.html) and also trigger your Lambda function. An example I can imagine in your case: when someone books something in your system or schedules it using your API, you setup a Step Function execution which will trigger your Lambda function at point X (or "waits" until that point in time) before the booking time. I've answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46935065/4831297 Maybe it's an alternative for you ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution. Will look into it :)